# django filter by manytomany or no record

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)

class PropertyType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)

class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = models.ForeignKey(PropertyType)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='properties')
    value = models.CharField(...)
```

So, how can i filter Products for properties with some value and property_type and include products, which have no property with same property_type

Something like this

```
properties = Property.objects.filter(property_type__pk=12, value='anyValue')
products = Product.objects.filter(Q(properties__in=properties)|
              Q(NO PROPERTY RECORD WITH PROPERTYTYPE__ID=12 FOR PRODUCT))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by experience

```
properties = Property.objects.filter(property_type__pk=12, value='anyValue')
products = Product.objects.filter(Q(properties__in=properties)|
          ~Q(properties__property_type__pk__in=[12]))
```

Comment: lol in fact what a I said, anyway if my answer helped you, pls voteup

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is `properties = Property.objects.filter(property_type__pk__contains=12, value='anyValue')` I didn't understand the second